# android programatically set Theme to edittext and add drawable background to button

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to programmatically create theme and set it to my Edittext. (I need to set colorControlNormal and colorControlActivated properties). So I guess I need somehow create theme in my code, give those 2 properties to it and than apply it to my Edittext.

Also I need to programatically give button the drawable background. But I need programmatically set color to this drawable stroke.

How can I achieve this in code?

Comment: You can't set  colorControlNormal and colorControlActivated. What is the final goal?

Comment: I must create library that takes object with 10 fields that represent colors. Than in my library I create fragment and programatically set those colors to follow the given design

Comment: Do you see other way to do this?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti